# Перебрать список, прошу помочь

Tags: python-3.x

Дан список, где элементы - списки. Пример:

```
[[137.0, '2021-01-22'], [139.0, '2021-01-23'], [142.0, '2021-01-26'], [137.0, '2021-01-27'], [142.0, '2021-01-28'], [137.0, '2021-01-29'], [142.0, '2021-01-30']]
```

Если заметили что списке значение 137.0 встречается 3 раза общем списке, вот если определенный элемент хотябы три раза или более встречается нужно дать сигнал, что и именно таких датах встречается одинаковые цены, а если меньше трех раз тогда игноририется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например можно сделать так (в лоб):

```
arr = [[137.0, '2021-01-22'], [139.0, '2021-01-23'], [142.0, '2021-01-26'], [137.0, '2021-01-27'], [142.0, '2021-01-28'], [137.0, '2021-01-29'], [132.0, '2021-01-30']]

res = [obj for obj in arr if len([1 for elem in arr if elem[0] == obj[0]]) >= 3]

print(res)
```

т.е. выделяем только те элементы, первый элемент которых встречается в массиве 3 раза и более

т.е.

проходим по всем элементам списка

```
for obj in arr
```

и для каждого элемента считаем сколько раз его первое значение встречается в массиве

```
len([1 for elem in arr if elem[0] == obj[0]])
```

в данном случае просто формируем произвольный массив и подсчитываем кол-во его элементов

тоже самое можно сделать чуть менее скотско и более читабельно:

```
res = [obj for obj in arr if [elem[0] for elem in arr].count(obj[0]) >= 3]
```

Comment: Супер получилось, извиняюсь за наглость, а как сделать так. если там цены не только 137 а еще 142 встречаются тогда они вместе в одном списке получаются в кашу, хочу сделать так {'137.0': ['2021-01-22', '2021-01-23','2021-01-24], '142.0': ['2021-01-25','2021-01-26','2021-01-27']}   прошу помочь

Comment: @django_starter, опять же в лоб можно - изначально превратить список в словарь - пройтись по всем элементам и собрать словарь по ключу

Comment: Не получилось, прошу помочь

Comment: задайте вопрос, приведите свой код и посмотрим где там ошибка, так проще будет